# Как при создании DataFrame из `pd.read_csv` пропустить первые строки?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, csv

При создании DataFrame из `pd.read_csv` надо пропустить первые 13 строк, чтобы заголовок был: `Pen Number; Date; Value`.

Код такой:

```
events_data = pd.read_csv('D:\Trend.csv', sep=';', decimal=',',skiprows=range(0, 12))
```

Выход:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Пример CSV:

```
Trend Name; Number of Curves; DateFrom; DateTo
"XXXXXXXX";10;"2019-10-01 14:30:03";"2019-10-08 14:30:03"
Pen Number; Pen Name; Minimum; Maximum
0;"Q0312";0,000000;100000,000000
1;"Q0323";0,000000;200000,000000
2;"Q0411";0,000000;100000,000000
3;"Т0533ВВ";-50,000000;200,000000
4;"Т0534АВ";-50,000000;200,000000
5;"Т0534ВВ";-50,000000;200,000000
6;"Т0536";0,000000;100,000000
7;"Т0555";0,000000;200,000000
8;"F0411";0,000000;180,000000
9;"F0222";0,000000;9,000000
Pen Number; Date; Value
0;"2019-10-01 14:30:03";88296,023438
0;"2019-10-01 14:38:45";88310,406250
0;"2019-10-01 14:38:46";88310,421875
0;"2019-10-01 14:47:29";88324,812500
0;"2019-10-01 14:47:29";88324,820313
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заранее прошу прощения  за оформление, это мой первый вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [skiprows=13](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=13)
```

Для приведенного в вопросе примера:

```
In [50]: pd.read_csv(r"C:\Temp\test.csv", skiprows=13, sep=";", 
                     skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=["Date"])
Out[50]:
   Pen Number                Date         Value
0           0 2019-10-01 14:30:03  88296,023438
1           0 2019-10-01 14:38:45  88310,406250
2           0 2019-10-01 14:38:46  88310,421875
3           0 2019-10-01 14:47:29  88324,812500
4           0 2019-10-01 14:47:29  88324,820313
```

---

**UPDATE:**  ваш файл имеет кодировку `'utf-16-le'` - именно поэтому у вас не получалось его правильно прочитать:

```
In [57]: pd.read_csv(r"C:\download\WinCC_OnlineTrendCtrl_2020_02_25_14_08_31.csv", 
                     skiprows=13,
                     sep=";", 
                     skipinitialspace=True, 
                     encoding="utf-16-le")    # <---- NOTE !!!
Out[57]:
       Pen Number                 Date          Value
0               0  2020-02-22 14:05:00  118001,453125
1               0  2020-02-22 14:08:43  118005,648438
2               0  2020-02-22 14:08:44  118005,664063
3               0  2020-02-22 14:12:28  118009,875000
4               0  2020-02-22 14:12:28  118009,882813
...           ...                  ...            ...
22699           9  2020-02-25 13:54:33       0,617188
22700           9  2020-02-25 13:58:04       0,617188
22701           9  2020-02-25 13:58:43       0,638021
22702           9  2020-02-25 14:01:19       0,617188
22703           9  2020-02-25 14:04:33       0,638021

[22704 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/446803)

Comment: @webDev_, текст ссылки и является ответом - параметр «skiprows=13» - это __весь__ ответ ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но данный способ не помог. Вместо данных, везде NaN

Comment: @Vladimir, что-то вы делаете не так. В вашем случае должно получиться три столбца, а у вас один. Можете выложить ваш CSV на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/TS4vB   Ок

Comment: Надеюсь у Вас получиться, сам удивлен что  параметр «skiprows=13» не работает.

Comment: @Vladimir, см. обновленный ответ...

Comment: Да, все отлично работает! Спасибо большое Вам!!!